# How do i hide fields through drop down

Tags: flutter, dart

How to hide visibility of forms through a drop down

The code:

```html
 Expanded(
   child:DropDownWidget(
     list: ["Yes","No"],
     data: patientConsent,
     hint: getTranslated(context, "select"),
     heading: getTranslated(context, "patient_consent"),

   ),
 ),
                            
 CustomFromField(
   heading: getTranslated(context, "sample_id"),
 ),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a ternary expression to check the value of your dropdown:

```dart
patientConsent == "Yes" ? 
    CustomFromField(
        heading: getTranslated(context, "sample_id"),
    ) : 
    SizedBox(),
```

You can also use an if expression:

```dart
if (patientConsent == "Yes")
    CustomFromField(
        heading: getTranslated(context, "sample_id"),
    ),
```